# How can I display web vitals metrics into my page footer with nextjs and react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Hi I'm just a newbie on next.js and react. I just find that next.js has a built-in function that can log performance metrics(e.g. fcp) into console that I would like to display it in my *Metric* component
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/measuring-performance

This is my *Metric* component:

```
export let fcpTime = 0;

const Metric = () => {
   // display metrics
   useEffect(() => {
       console.log("fcpTime: ", fcpTime); // fcpTime still = 0
   }, []);
}

export default Metric;
```

I tried to set `fcpTime` inside the `case 'FCP':`

```
// pages/_app.js
export function reportWebVitals(metric) {
  switch (metric.name) {
    case 'FCP':
      // handle FCP results
      fcpTime = metric.value;
      break
    case 'LCP':
      // handle LCP results
      break
    case 'CLS':
      // handle CLS results
      break
    case 'FID':
      // handle FID results
      break
    case 'TTFB':
      // handle TTFB results
      break
    default:
      break
  }
}
```

However, how can I can pass the FCP result to my component and make it re-render again when FCP result is logged? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I dispatch a `new CustomEvent` and useEffect to addEventListener into this custom event. Here is the code:

_app.js

```
export function reportWebVitals(result) {
  if (result.name === "FCP") {
    dispatchFcpEvent(result);
  }
};
```

Metric.js

```
let fcpEvent = null;

export const dispatchFcpEvent = (fcp) => {
  fcpEvent = new CustomEvent('fcpTime', { detail: fcp.value });
  window.dispatchEvent(fcpEvent);
}

const Copyright = () => {
  const [fcpTime, setFcpTime] = useState();

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const onFcpTimeUpdate = (e) => {
      setFcpTime(e.detail);
      window.removeEventListener('fcpTime', onFcpTimeUpdate, false);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('fcpTime', onFcpTimeUpdate);
    }, []);
  }

  // return below
  ...
}
```